# Using regex in find and replace script for Illustrator

Tags: javascript, regex, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

This script was created by another user and then I tweaked it a bit, you can see more about it on [this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/122080/63979)

---

This is the script:

```
#target illustrator
var doc = app.activeDocument;

jsfind = prompt("Find: ", "");
jsreplace = prompt("Replace: ", "");

for ( var i=0; i<doc.artboards.length ;i++) {
var aBoard = doc.artboards[i].active;
var oldName = doc.artboards[i].name;
doc.artboards[i].name = oldName.replace (jsfind, jsreplace);
}
```

I want to make `jsfind` use regex for "find"

If I just switch

```
oldName.replace (jsfind, jsreplace);
```

to

```
oldName.replace (/jsfind/g, jsreplace);
```

It doesn't function properly, I assume I have to excape the characters or something, but I'm not sure.

Comment: `var regex = new RegExp(jsfind,"g");` and use it as `oldName.replace(regex, jsreplace);`

Comment: @adiga that worked, post it as an answer and I'll accept!

Comment: You're welcome. You can [accept the duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250930/289255)